# Print a shuffled deck of cards

Tags: code-golf, string, random, unicode

### Input

None

### Output

52 cards. No duplicates. Cards are represented as their unicode characters, e.g. .

The [Unicode codepoints](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F0A0.pdf) follow the following format:

- The first three digits are `1F0`.
- The next digit is `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` for spades, hearts, diamonds, and clubs respectively.
- The next digit is `1` through `C` and `E` for the various numbers/face cards. `1` is ace, `2`-`A` are the number cards, and `B`, `D`,  and `E` are the jack, queen, and king respectively. (`C` is the knight, which isn't in most decks.)

**Example output:**

### Rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer wins.
- [Forbidden loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Your deck must be actually randomized. If run 20 times, 20 random (and most likely unique) outputs must be generated.

### Note

If you only see boxes, install [the DejaVu fonts](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59883/discussion-between-nooneishere-and-mendeleev).

Comment: Can there be spaces between each character?

Comment: I think you mean it should be random and that all permutations should have a none zero probability of occurrence.

Comment: Who else is seeing a bunch of boxes?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Read the bottom section

Comment: @Mendeleev you should also post a warning that that download is almost a gigabyte!

Comment: @Noodle9 That's only if you download the CJK fonts. All the other ones should be less than 50M total, and you should only need Sans, Serif, and Mono anyway.

Comment: The example output is showing as just 52 boxes for me.

Comment: @carusocomputing Please read the bottom section of the challenge

Comment: *If you only see boxes, install Google's Noto fonts.* Yeah, I can't do that on my phone...

Comment: From which of the linked fonts are these cards? I've installed all of them (except for NotoColorEmoji.ttf, which gives an error), but I still see boxes..

Comment: Noto Emoji contains *one* playing card (U+1F0CF PLAYING CARD BLACK JOKER), and it doesn't even appear in your challenge!

Comment: Ooooops... I linked the wrong fonts!

Comment: @Dennis Should be fixed now

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Should be fixed now

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Try installing the newly linked fonts

Comment: Can confirm, DejaVu Sans is what my desktop computer uses by default and indeed has the playing cards.

Comment: @carusocomputing I've updated the font section, try again

Comment: Is the Knight used in any set of cards? Google searches seem to suggest tarot cards?

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25 23</s>  21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
62R%⁴g180<11T+“¢¬⁷’ẊỌ
```

A niladic link returning a list of characters, or a full program that prints the shuffled deck.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//NjJSJeKBtGcxODA8MTFUK@KAnMKiwqzigbfigJnhuorhu4z///Vuby1jYWNoZQ)**

#### How?

```
62R%⁴g180<11T+“¢¬⁷’ẊỌ - Main link: no arguments
62                    - literal 62
  R                   - range(62) -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31, 32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47, 48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62]
    ⁴                 - literal 16
   %                  - modulo    -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14]
      180             - literal 180
     g                - G.C.D.    -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,4,9,10, 1,12, 1, 2,15,180, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9,10, 1,12, 1, 2,15,180, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9,10, 1,12, 1, 2,15,180, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9,10, 1,12, 1, 2]
          11          - literal 11
         <            - less than?-> [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
            T         - truthy    -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,   13,14,       17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,   29,30,       33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,   45,46,       49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,   61,62]
              “¢¬⁷’   - base 250 number 127136
             +        - addition (vectorises) -> card character ordinals
                   Ẋ  - shuffle the list
                    Ọ - convert to characters
                      - full program has an implicit print
```

Comment: Why is it always Jelly that does this magic?

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>107</s> <s>106</s> 108 bytes

```
a=[]
for(S of'ABCD')for(N of'123456789ABDE')a.splice(Math.random()*-~a.length,0,eval(`'\\u\{1F0${S+N}}'`))
a
```

```js
a=[]
for(S of'ABCD')for(N of'123456789ABDE')a.splice(Math.random()*-~a.length,0,eval(`'\\u\{1F0${S+N}}'`))
a

o.innerHTML = a.join``
```

```html
<div id=o style="font-size:80px"></div>
```

<sub>-1 byte thanks to [@nderscore](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124565/print-a-shuffled-deck-of-cards/124606#comment306395_124606)</sub>

---

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>120</s> <s>119</s> 121 bytes

Previous version.

```
a=[],[...'ABCD'].map(S=>[...'123456789ABCE'].map(N=>a.splice(Math.random()*-~a.length|0,0,eval("'\\u\{1F0"+S+N+"}'")))),a
```

Comment: Whoa, never seen `[...'ABCD']` before. That's cool :)

Comment: @SteveBennett Indeed! It's nice that strings are iterable by char like that. :)

Comment: But you still can't do things like `"ABCD".map(...)`. I'm sure there are sensible reasons why that's the case.

Comment: @SteveBennett Yeah, I'd guess it's because it's ambiguous whether such a method would return a string or an array.

Comment: The `map` method is only part of the Array prototype, not the String prototype.

Comment: Very nice one. I took the liberty of modifying the snippet for a more graphical output, but feel free to rollback.

Comment: -1 byte with `eval(\`'\\u\{1F0${S+N}}'\`)`

Comment: @Arnauld Awesome, thanks! Nice to hear from a well seasoned JS golfer. :)

Comment: @nderscore Done.

Comment: `123456789ABCE` includes the cavaliers in the output instead of the queens; it should be `123456789ABDE`.

Comment: Also, this always places the ace of spades last.

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed the queens. Including the ace of spades in the shuffle cost me two bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>106</s>  94 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to musicman523 (1. use `sample(...,52)` as an inline equivalent to `shuffle` [thanks to totallyhuman]; 2. use `~v&2` instead of `v%4<2`; plus a further 1 byte as a consequence as a space may be removed)

```python
from random import*
print(*sample([chr(v+127137)for v in range(63)if~v&2or~v%16>4],52),sep='')
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDsIgFADQ3VOw2EKtA2DbSS9iHAiCkAj/55eQdOmtnVGnNz3cSoCsW/MEiZHJzx8xIVAZDkgxFz6sJuHb8bsNxOtJqkXqRXggVlnM//NyfNYi@r12CmivRznfLo9xUmJcHV77XrT2yXC2xgb3BQ)**

Comment: Well I wasn't able to get my own Python solution any better, but I got yours down to 97 using totallyhuman's switch to `sample`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDsIgFEDR3a9gaQptHQBtl/oljQNBEBJ5j7wSEj@8M9rpDic3f0tA0K15wsTIwOufmDJSGS6ZIhQ@7Cblj@ObDcTrKNUi9SI8Eqsswvm8HZ@1iJ7VTs6rlCd1t1U9p7sS0@7yo@9Fawfg1Rob3A8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Additionally, you can change `v%4<2` to `~v&2` to save one more byte.

Comment: Nicely done! I had thought maybe another `random` function could help there. Another byte on top as `or ~...` can be `or~...`.

Answer (score 6):

## Bash + coreutils, 56 bytes

```sh
printf %b\\n \\U1F0{A..D}{{1..9},A,B,D,E}|shuf|tr -d \\n
```

We use `printf` to write each card on its own line, shuffle the lines, then concatenate all the lines by removing the newline characters.

Note that although the coreutils `printf` command requires exactly 8 hexadecimal digits after `\U`, the Bash built-in `printf` lets us omit leading zeros.

Comment: I got as far as `echo 16iF09F8{2A,2B,38,39}{{1..9},A,B,D,E}0AP|dc|shuf|tr -d \\n`, but yours is better.  I didn't know about `%b`.

Comment: @Digital - neither did I, until writing this answer!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *carusocomputing*.

```
…1F0A4£14L13KhJâ«Hç.r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f8wNWFiMWX//@KApjFGMEE0wqMxNEwxM0toSsOiwqtIw6cucv//9W5vLWNhY2hl)

**Explanation**

```
…1F0                    # push the string "1F0"
    A4£                 # push the string "abcd"
       14L              # push range [1 ... 14]
          13K           # remove 13
             h          # convert to hexadecimal
              J         # join to string "123456789ABCE"
               â        # cartesian product
                «       # prepend the string to each char in the list
                 H      # convert to decimal
                  ç     # get the chars with those code points
                   .r   # randomize
```

Comment: `…1F0A4£14L13KhJâ«Hç.r` for 21 bytes (edited because I forgot to remove knights). Does help you tie jelly though.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Good idea to do the cartesian before the concatenation, so we can skip the split. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @totallyhuman and 3 thanks to @CCB60!

```python
from random import*
print(*sample([chr(int('1F0'+a+b,16))for a in'ABCD'for b in'123456789ABDE'],52),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaGgVJ@YW5KRqRCdnFGmABNQN3QzUtRO1k3QMzTQ10/KLFBIVMvPUHZ2cXdRBvCQQz9DI2MTUzNzC0tHJxVU9VsfUSFOnOLXAVl1d8///r3n5usmJyRmpAAA)

Comment: [Golfed it a little.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaGgVJ@YW5KRqRCdnFGmABNLUDSoM3QyqE2urk2rVdQzNNDXT8osUEhUy89QdnZxd1EG8JBDP0MjYxNTM3MLS0cnFVT1Wx9RIU/P//695@brJickZqQA "Python 3 – Try It Online") This is only valid if spaces are allowed as separators though.

Comment: @totallyhuman adding `,sep=''` fixes the spaces, of course – but makes it 112 bytes

Comment: I forgot about `random.sample`! I'll let the OP decide about spaces. I can add `,sep=''` to get rid of them, and still save 6 bytes.

Comment: chr(int(f'0x1F0{a}{b}',16)) can be shortened by 3 bytes to chr(int('0x1F0'+a+b,16))

Comment: @CCB60 I'm a fool. Good catch

Comment: @musicman523 You mean you're a 

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 112 bytes

```python
from random import*
*a,=map(chr,range(127136,127200))
del a[::16],a[::-15],a[11::14]
shuffle(a)
print(*a,sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczBCoMwEATQe77Cm4mk4GprQfBLioelJo1gkmVND/36dD29YQaGfiXkNNbqOceGMW3CHilz6VSHdolI@h3YyvRxGoYnjJMVhr43Rm3uaPA1zzCt9vIGjysASHVf1Rm@3h9Oo1HEeypaHk9HS9uaWv8)

Comment: Can you explain the magic going on in the del statement?  I've been trying to figure it out by breaking it down into three sequential statements, but I end up deleting the wrong items in the list.  For example, a[::16] gives me one card and three uninterpreted unicodes.

Comment: The `del` statement does break down sequentially from left to right. The first element of of `a[::16]` is U+1F0A0 PLAYING CARD BACK, which should be deleted. We also need to delete the Knight and Joker cards that are stuck in between the normal 52. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode#Playing_cards_deck.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
Ａ¹²⁷¹³⁶χＡ⪫Ｅ…χ⁺⁶⁴χ℅ιωσＷσ«Ａ‽σχＡ⪫⪪σχωσ¿﹪﹪﹪℅χ¹⁶¦¹⁵¦¹³χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDoIwDIbP4yl27BI4IIoHT8abCZHoEywDoUnZyAZyMD773CKJxkP/pn/b71e9tMpI8v7oHHYa8s0@L8qUK3FIVutsUEMlR7hK3bWgUl7T7KDcxiuR8lNgSDW1FjCOSygXvpceqeXgBH8mbEUFQmOG4H0C2G/CbSScwMXNF8LwzqEyzUzmr11sg1oSxOu8jLKLUgiRMFZb1BPEiJf3Pnv4zNEb) Link is to verbose version of code. Creates the string of all the 64 characters in the block but filters invalid cards out as they are randomly selected. (Speaking of which, random selection without replacement from a string is only 11 bytes, compared to 17 for an array.)

Edit: Subtraction from an array and other Charcoal improvements have cut down the size to 41 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy9DsIgFIVneIo73pvQoVbr4GScGxt9AqTVkiBYaHUwPjtC1MXlnOQ7P2qQXjlpYtyGoC8WG3nDeilglwKppt5ja@aA5WJdVrUATUQCRtrwx6BNDzgSPDn7jg/Sdu6amIAhVX74OJ@mfIZj5p8502fAxnWzcX@295220mBulnWWVZaKiDPWem0nzOevGGNxj0Uwbw)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/)>=7, 102 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<64;)in_array(($c=127136+$i)%16,[0,12,15])?:$q[]=IntlChar::chr($c);shuffle($q);echo join($q);
```

No Online Interpreter available for the [IntlChar::chr](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.chr.php) method

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 112 bytes

```php
for(;$n++<4;shuffle($r))for($i=0;$i++<14;)$i==12?:$r[]=pack("c*",240,159,131-($n>2),$n*16+112+$i);echo join($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsIwFAB3v0LkDUmTQl@sgqa1g3Rw0cVNpJSQmqgkIerqXzvHdrw7uGBCqppgwkzH6GMXdfDxbd2NfNvueDof9i2VafCRSHCMVaV8mc8wPDWBSOnkwdaFBDs2LCUdqUbRbCFernXo1YMsVLbgoiw4rjYcl5gTcDtBObgM1wxRMLBUamX8/O6tm74ypZ/zueqV0X8)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 116 bytes

```php
for(;$c=ab89[$n++];shuffle($r))for($i=0;$i++<14;)$i==12?:$r[]=hex2bin(f09f8.(2+($n>2)).$c.dechex($i));echo join($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxDsIgFEV3v8LhDbwQm5Y4tFLsYDq46OJmmqZFEIwBgpo4@dfOiNu9OefeYEJqu2DCQsXo4xhV8PFp3ZV8@vFwPO13PfKkfSQcpJjmujmDo3TgD/PS@q4IRMQ/BitKDpbStlpzzE1UrNtAPA/CqDebrSO6bHRdEEYJuC1DLEAWFyUzzmtEnqNf3nw28ylP6ev8Sk6Z/wA)

## PHP, 121 Bytes

```php
for(;$c=ABCD[$n++];shuffle($r))for($i=0;$i++<14;)$i==12?:$r[]=json_decode('"\ud83c\udc'.$c.dechex($i).'"');echo join($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxbC8IgGIb/SowPVCRp1UXMyejwL9aI8ICOUHEM@uNd27ebF573lH2u/ZBRXSpUglbX2/0xQuR8kotfnftYCoWxLYagDhIC5317lgxJtcehgzJOal5SfBmrk7GUNM/VXE4aVRMBWqDv7RfnTJCGMImYdnMKcXuWtf5i2us3dv4)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

#### [Jonathan Allan's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124569/43319)

```apl
⎕UCS((11>180∨16|⍳62)/127136+⍳62)[?⍨52]
```

`(`…`)` on the following array

`⍳62` the first 62 integers

`127136+` add 127136 to that

`(`…`)/` filter that with the Boolean

`⍳62` first 62 integers

`16|` modulus 16

`180∨` GCD of 180 and that

`11>` whether 11 is greater than those

`[`…`]` select the following elements

`?⍨52` shuffle the first 52 integers (pick 52 random integers out of a bag of the first 52 integers)

`⎕UCS` convert to corresponding symbols in the **U**nicode **C**haracter **S**et

---

#### Version 16.0 (currently in beta) solution (33 characters)

```apl
⎕UCS(127136+⍸11>180∨16|⍳62)[?⍨52]
```

`(`…`)` on the following array

`⍳62` first 62 integers

`16|` modulus 16

`180∨` GCD of 180 and that

`11>` whether 11 is greater than those

`⍸` indices where True

`127136+` add 127136 to that

`[`…`]` select the following elements

`?⍨52` shuffle the first 52 integers (pick 52 random integers out of a bag of the first 52 integers)

`⎕UCS` convert to corresponding symbols in the **U**nicode **C**haracter **S**et

---

#### Old solution

```apl
⎕UCS(126976+16⊥¨,(9+⍳4)∘.,12~⍨⍳14)[?⍨52]
```

`(`…`)` on the following array

`⍳14` the first 14 integers

`12~⍨` except 12

`(`…`)∘.,` Cartesianly concatenated to

`⍳4` the first 4 integers

`9+` added to 9

`,` ravel (flatten) that

`16⊥¨` evaluate each in base 16

`126976+` add 126976 to that

`[`…`]` select the following elements

`?⍨52` shuffle the first 52 integers (pick 52 random integers out of a bag of the first 52 integers)

`⎕UCS` convert to corresponding symbols in the **U**nicode **C**haracter **S**et

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
kA4Ẏk^ḢṪ\DoẊ`1F0`vpHCÞ℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrQTThuo5rXuG4ouG5qlxcRG/huopgMUYwYHZwSEPDnuKEhSIsIiIsIiJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
kA4Ẏk^ḢṪ\DoẊ`1F0`vpHCÞ℅
kA4Ẏ                    # Get the first 4 letters of the uppercase alphabet
    k^                  # Push string "0123456789ABCDEF"
      ḢṪ                # Remove head and tail: "123456789ABCDE"
        \Do             # Remove the D: "123456789ABCE"
           Ẋ            # Cartesian product of strings: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", ..., "DC", "DE"]
            `1F0`       # Push string "1FO"
                 vp     # Prepend to each: ["1FOA1", "1FOA2", ..., "1FODE"]
                   H    # Convert each from hexadecimal: [127137, 127137, ..., 127198]
                    C   # Convert each to their unicode representation: ["", "", ... ""]
                     Þ℅ # Randomly shuffle
```

Port of Jelly is same byte count:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
62ɾ16%180ġ11<T»ƛǔḭ»+CÞ℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI2Msm+MTYlMTgwxKExMTxUwrvGm8eU4bitwrsrQ8Oe4oSFIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### How?

```
62ɾ16%180ġ11<T»ƛǔḭ»+CÞ℅
62ɾ                     # Push range [1, 2, ..., 62]
   16%                  # Modulo each by 16
      180ġ              # GCD each with 180: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9, 10, ..., 12, 1, 2]
          11<T          # Indices where item is less than 11: [0, 1, 2, 3, ... 13, 16, 17, ..., 26, ...]
              »ƛǔḭ»     # Push compressed integer 127137
                   +    # Add to each (vectorizes)
                    C   # Convert each to their unicode representation
                     Þ℅ # Randomly shuffle
```

For both solutions, add `s` flag if it needs to be a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 34 bytes

```
'?rwd.n$@U,!6?44*%a7+-F$K?'+OK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/dvqg8RS9PxSFUR9HM3sRESzXRXFvXTcXbXv3D/KaF2v7e//9/zcvXTU5MzkgFAA)

#### Explanation

```
'?r                               push numbers 0-63 onto stack
   w                              store return address (start main loop)
    d                             get stack depth
     .n$@                         if zero, terminate
         U                        random number in [0, depth)
          ,                       move corresponding stack element to top
           !                      store on tape
             ?                    copy back from tape
              44*%                mod 16
                  a7+-            subtract 17
            6         F           does the result divide 6?
                       $K         if so, return to start of main loop
                         ?        copy card number from tape again
                          '+     add 0x1F0A1
                             O    output
                              K   return to start of main loop
```

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>49</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
""v
=?v>:1+}:88+%:c-:3-**?!~{l4d*
{>x
o^>l?!;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X@nD/KaFSmVctvZldlaG2rVWFhbaqlbJulbGulpa9op11TkmKVpc1XYVXPlxdjn2itb//3/Ny9dNTkzOSAUA)

*(+1 byte to make the randomness better)*

I'm interpreting "random" to mean "every possible outcome has a non-zero probability". This isn't a uniform distribution.

There are two stages to this code. First, the fish puts all the cards on the stack, using the first two lines. Starting with the ace of spades, the fish duplicates and increments it, then checks if the previous card's hex code ends in  0, C or F by multiplying together *x* (*x*-12) (*x*-15), where *x* is the charcode mod 16, and checking if that's zero. If it is, it deletes the offending card from the stack. It repeats until the stack has 52 cards, then swims into stage 2:

```
  v
{>x
o^>l?!;
```

This bit of code shuffles and prints the stack. The `x` sets the fish's direction randomly:

- If the fish swims up, it hits the `v` and goes back to the `x` without doing anything. The left direction is similar.
- If the fish swims right, it wraps and hits the `{`, rotating the entire stack to the left, then returns to the `x`.
- If the fish swims down, it prints the card at the front of the stack then returns to the `x`.

It's clear that every possible order of the cards can be produced: at any point in stage 2, every card that hasn't been printed yet can be printed next if the fish swims rightwards enough times. This shuffling technique usually doesn't move cards very far apart if they were already near each other, but then again, [neither does shuffling by hand](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/overhand2.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

## R, 61 bytes

```
cat(intToUtf8(sample(c(127137:127198)[-c(12,28,44,47,60)])))
```

Randomly sample the vector of integer representations of the cards unicode values (which can be obtained from `utf8ToInt()` fucntion) and remove the unwanted knight/joker cards.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUKjODG3ICdVQ8PQyNzQ2Ezb0MrMSDNaNxnI1zGy0DEx0TEx1zEz0IzV1NT8/x8A "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### C# (<strike>146</strike> 141 bytes)

```
using System.Linq;()=>Enumerable.Range(0,52).OrderBy(i=>System.Guid.NewGuid()).Aggregate("",(s,i)=>s+"\uD83C"+(char)(56481+i+i/13*3+i%13/12))
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/BgEiYG)

This uses extremely bad style in shuffling with `Guid.NewGuid()`, but it's code-golf. It then builds the surrogate pairs manually.

Comment: Does this actually work? Whenever I tried casting the dynamic int to a char, it threw an exception?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, I don't have any dynamic values. But as proof that it works, I've attached an Ideone link.

Comment: I meant the int created for the second part of the surrogate pair.

Comment: You can save a byte by not including the trailing semicolon

Comment: Says 147 bytes, reads as 146

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 75 bytes

```pl
@c=map{7946+$_%4+$_/64}4..51,56..59;print chr(16*splice@c,@c*rand,1)while@c
```

Note that this uses the code points for queens as given in the question (i.e. last digit `C`). For the actual code points (last digit `D`), replace `51,56` with `47,52`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 216 bytes

```
import java.util.*;()->{List<Long>l=new ArrayList();for(long i=52;i-->0;l.add(i));Collections.shuffle(l);for(Long x:l)System.out.print((char)(x.parseLong("1F0"+(char)(65+x/12)+((x%=4)>9?(char)(x>2?69:65+x):x),16)));}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##PVDLbsIwELznK1ZIlezSmIcKEqQJqir1RFEljlUPi@MQU2NHtkODEJ/dc3AK7WWlndnZ3ZkdHjA2ldC7/KuV@8pYD7uAsdpLxe4TGAzgHQNoCvClgM3Ri5ibWvso4gqdgzeU@hQBSO2FLZALWHUtwMHIHDihSejOUSjOo5ccVqAhhZbQODstpfNPS6O3mUq1@IZna/HYgUFWGEtUoECmk3Ei4zgbJophnhNJafJilBLcS6Mdc2VdFEoQdRV1@6CZK7o@Oi/2zNSeVTb8Rwgv0VLSsAqtE90c6Y1eh73@jZhO@s1gNKZ9Qpq79JFms8WfJBsvprN5N0DnDX0YTWl44twmnbGq3qhg7Obv1/c@pELWPlzdfnwC0mskmv3ncW5/tIk58lJcAA)

NOTE: Untested because even though I've installed the linked font, I still see boxes. Probably have to restart my PC or something..

```
import java.util.*;               // Required import for List, ArrayList and Collections
()->{                             // Method without parameter nor return-type
  List<Long>l=new ArrayList();    //  List
  for(long i=52;i-->0;l.add(i));  //  Fill the list with 1 through 52
  Collections.shuffle(l);         //  Randomly shuffle the list
  for(Long x:l)                   //  Loop over the shuffled list
    System.out.print(             //   Print the following character:
      (char)(x.parseLong(         //    Convert the following String to a character:
        "1F0"+                    //     The literal String "1F0" +
         (char)(65+x/12)+         //     either A, B, C or D by using x/12, adding 65,
                                  //      and casting it to a char +
         ((x%=4)>9?               //     If the current item mod-4 is 10 or higher:
            (char)(x>2?69:65+x)   //      Convert it to A, B, C or E
           :                      //     Else (1 through 9):
            x)                    //      Simply add this digit
      ,16))
    );
}                                 // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>51</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 22 bytes

With some inspiration from [Jonathan's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124569/58974).

```
#?ö¬k@B§XuG y#´Ãmd##
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Iz/2rGtAQqdYdUcgeSO0w21kI38jiA==&input=LVM=) (or [view output with increased `font-size`](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Iz/2rGtAQqdYdUcgeSO0w21kI38jiA==&input=LVM=))

---

### Explanation

```
#?                         :63
  ö¬                       :Random permutation of range [0,63)
    k                      :Remove elements that return true
     @                     :When passed through this function
      B                    :  11
       §                   :  Less than or equal to
        X                  :  Current element
         u                 :  Modulo
          G                :  16
            y              :  GCD
             #´            :  180
               Ã           :End function
                m          :Map
                  ##       :  Add 127136
                 d         :  Get character at that codepoint
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 35 bytes

```
⎕ucs(∊127150+(16×⍳4)-⊂2~⍨⍳14)[?⍨52]
```

based on [Adám's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124565/print-a-shuffled-deck-of-cards#answer-125024)

uses `⎕io←0`