# 9/10 Geometers agree, Nepal has the coolest flag

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Given no input, output the following:

```
 _
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~     ~-_
|    ＼~~~~~~
|  *   ＼
|        ＼
|~~~~~~~~~~＼
```

Note the backslashes are actually `＼`, which is `U+FF3C`

Trailing whitespace is allowed, however leading whitespace is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: Not as cool as in [Let's draw the flag of Nepal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/lets-draw-the-flag-of-nepal). While you ask Unicode character instead of backslash, you could ask for `⏝` U+23dd (bottom parenthesis) instead of tilde under the Sun.

Comment: @manatwork would've had I known about said character before-hand, making ascii-art by hand isn't the easiest thing :P

Comment: Why don't you use a backslash? Some languages struggle with unicode characters.

Comment: @Okx I don't see a problem with that. For example, [Print a shuffled deck of cards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124565/print-a-shuffled-deck-of-cards/124693#124693), my C# answer here was fun to solve because C# struggles with surrogate pairs when creating those strings.

Comment: @Okx it makes the challenge a little more interesting

Comment: "9/10 Geometers agree" citation please?

Comment: Despite my happiness to see my country's flag in codegolf, I must say that this is a very bad ascii rendition of Nepali flag.. :D

Comment: Tagged ASCII art, demands non-ASCII characters...

Comment: "a little more interesting" Not really IMO. Please explain why.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder : Yours or Peter Taylor's answer?

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>94</s> <s>92</s> 96 bytes

```
print(""" _
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~     ~-_
|    ＼~~~~~~
|  *   ＼
|        ＼
|~~~~~~~~~~＼""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0lJSSGeq0ahThdE5itAGXUKIABhA8H7PXvqwADE1YIIQGQUYJw6OABygaZq/v8PAA)

Comment: Why the `\n` at the very end? You don't have to output a trailing new-line.

Comment: Also, not sure who downvoted you, but I upvoted to neutralize it. Welcome too PPCG! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [Sympathy voting isn't recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site). To the OP, I suggest adding a try it online link to an implementation of your answer (see other answers for link/examples), it helps people validate your code.

Comment: I'm counting 97 bytes, 89 chars.

Comment: @Notts90 does help to downvote & say nothing! Can confirm.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 50 bytes

```
•ζ1VS¹Tšã¦1d’sΩç!ÙT>_äтÿÀ†{ECZ{Ý•7ÝJ"_ -~|＼*o"‡8¡»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVsApP8wNWFiMWX//@KAos62MVZTwrlUxaHDo8KmMWTigJlzzqnDpyHDmVQ@X8Ok0YLDv8OA4oCge0VDWnvDneKAojfDnUoiXyAtfnzvvLwqbyLigKE4wqHCu///QUJD)

---

First I created a translation table as follows:

```
0   | "_"
1   | " "
2   | "-"
3   | "~"
4   | "|"
5   | "＼"
6   | "*"
7   | "o"
8   | "\n"
```

I then proceeded to replace each unique character in the flag with the number corresponding to the character at that specific position to get the number:

```
108413208417113208413111113208411115333333841161115841111111158433333333335
```

Here's the same pattern with the newlines (makes it more obvious):

```
10
41320
41711320
41311111320
411115333333
41161115
4111111115
433333333335
```

[I then compressed the number into base-255 using 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0MDCxNDYCESaG0IZxoYgAGEDgakxGIA4ZiAuRNQQwjSGA1MFI1NTp///AQ) (To compress a base-10 number to base 255 simply run 255B in 05AB1E).

Then, see the code explanation for how I rebuild it from the number.

---

```
•ζ1VS¹Tšã¦1d’sΩç!ÙT>_äтÿÀ†{ECZ{Ý• # Push the number we discussed.
7ÝJ                               # Push 01234567.
   "_ -~|＼*o"                    # Push "_ -~|＼*o".
              ‡                   # Replace 0-7 with the appropriate block.
               8¡»                # Split on 8's and print with newlines.
```

Comment: I had glanced at base 255 compression but never really understood it. This is great!

Comment: This is actually 78 bytes, because this program cannot be encoded in 05AB1E's native encoding and so must be encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>83 79</s> 78 bytes (UTF-8)

```
" _
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~     ~-_
|    ＼~~~~~~
|  *   ＼
|{8ç}＼
|{Aç'~}＼
```

Hardcodes most of the string

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IiBfCnwgfi1fCnwgbyAgfi1fCnwgfiAgICAgfi1fCnwgICAgXHVmZjNjfn5+fn5+CnwgICogICBcdWZmM2MKfHs4531cdWZmM2MKfHtB5yd+fVx1ZmYzYw==&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 49 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
⁰∑J“ζ"Ω‰Θx(;╝φ╚○Δ§∆qσG⅛>K█׀IR'ΚΧqΞ⅞≥№█▼¡└+Β8‘# ~ŗ
```

If the flag used any other character than `~`, this would be 4 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 66 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @carusocomputing

```
'~T×ð8×'~6×ð5×" _
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~ÿ~-_
|    ＼ÿ
|  *   ＼
|ÿ＼
|ÿ＼"
```

String interpolation replaces the `ÿ`s. In order from first to last, it is: 5 spaces, 6 `~`s, 8 spaces, and then 10 `~`s

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fvS7k8PTDGywOT1evMwOxTA9PV1KI56pRqNMFkfkKUEbd4f0QBhC837Pn8H4QUwvC4ao5vB9BKf3/DwA)

Comment: This is perfect for String Interpolation! https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fvS7k8PTDGywOT1dSiOeqUajTBZH5ClBGnQIIQNhA8H7PnjowAHG1IAJcNYf3Iyil//8B

Comment: Basically, what it's doing is the `ÿ` will pop whatever was previous on the stack and throw it directly into the string, so first we push the 10 tildes followed by the 8 spaces then use two `ÿ` inside of the string to slam them into it! Saves you 4 bytes and is uncommonly seen ;). A nifty trick few people utilize.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Did not notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for these types of challenges see my answer here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124965/59376 (I only answered to explain base conversion to you =])

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 89 bytes

```c#
_=>@" _
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~     ~-_
|    ＼~~~~~~
|  *   ＼
|        ＼
|~~~~~~~~~~＼"
```

Any formatting options in C# for this require too many extra bytes that it is just cheaper to hard code the output as far as I can tell.

Comment: is the `@` needed? Are there any characters in there that would need to be escaped otherwise?

Comment: The `@` is needed to tell the compiler the string will wrap onto newlines. That is shorter than hard coding all the line feeds. No chars need escaping.

Comment: aaah right, didn't realise `@` also allowed a string to be multiline

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
“ ½|~-o*_‘;65340Ọ“ßṆiṣ€|ʂwĊeḌ\<S@DƝbƘ×©ṗþ8¥Ḅ3Zȥ ’ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV4Aof9qZWxsef//4oCcIMK9fH4tbypf4oCYOzY1MzQw4buM4oCcw5/huYZp4bmj4oKsfMqCd8SKZeG4jFw8U0BExp1ixpjDl8Kp4bmXw744wqXhuIQzWsilIOKAmeG5g///)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 96 bytes

```
()->" _\n| ~-_\n| o  ~-_\n| ~     ~-_\n|    ＼~~~~~~\n|  *   ＼\n|        ＼\n|~~~~~~~~~~＼"
```

Boring, but it probably can't be shortened by using some fancy `.replace` or loops anyway in Java..

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##PY9BDoIwEEX3nuKHVTGBCxC9gWxcqjG1VFPElkAhMUpPxp08Ag5Q@Gkz8zrJ/N@ctzwypdR59hxEwesaB670ZwMobWV150IiHRE42krpBwQLE@KOLp3acqsEUmjsMLAw2ge4nvUXLpqKwdK5cccCpF/fu0kTb@cXP8NKbhVxMCSza9ncCnL15q1RGV4Um80RTxfw0Gd@11a@YtPYuKSRZTqm/P4D3fAH)

Comment: According to the meta post, can't you take an unused argument to save a byte?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Well, I consider [the question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) to be still in process. And since the only answer stating Yes only has 1 upvote so far, I don't think it's valid (yet).

Comment: Sounds about right then :)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 84 bytes

```
"_
| ~-_
| o  ~-_
| ~     ~-_
|    ＼~~~~~~
|  *   ＼
|        ＼
|~~~~~~~~~~＼"
```

Comment: Missing a space between `"_`?

Answer (score 0):

## Bubblegum, 40

Not sure why no-one posted the bubblegum answer yet - Is bubblegum frowned upon these days?

xxd dump:

```
00000000: 5388 e7aa 51a8 d305 91f9 0a50 469d 0210  S...Q......PF...
00000010: 40d9 40f0 7ecf 9e3a 3000 71b5 2002 1019  @.@.~..:0.q. ...
00000020: 0518 a70e 0e80 5c00                      ......\.
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bY4xDsIwFEN3TuETfPkn/STp1IkZxMqStCkLDAysXD1EFImFN3ix/OTyLOVWr897a/wywnyMqCFnmOaIxdOQdE1gNmLYpwV0SuAsIif5cDz02G0G7Y6BS@qxEqHOK1L1Gb53CFoMjnRQagImmeQlMlIegp/DdQdNI3JgBWskbO7zv2wXLtLaGw).

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
1_!1~-_!1o2~-_!1~5~-_!4＼""!2*3＼!8＼!"""~＼
"
~~~
!
¶|
\d
$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fyzBe0bBOF0jkG4GpOlMQZfJ@zx4lJUUjLWMgQ9ECRCgpKdUBaS4lrrq6Oi5FrkPbarhiUrhUtBT@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
←×~χ↑⁷ _Ｐ¶¶o¶~¶¶ *Ｆ³¶~-_↓←×~⁶Ｆ⁴«＼↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJzWtREchJDM3tVhDqU5JR8HQQFPTmgsqG1qgo2AO5yopxCsBOb6lOSWZBRCRmLyYvPyYvDoQraAFkk3LL1LQMNZUCIApqNOF6MovS9Wwcskvz0MYj2G5mSbMBBNNhWouTqgh7/fsARnBiTAjKDM9owQoVPv//3/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
←×~χ
```

Print the bottom `~`s.

```
↑⁷
```

Print the left `|`s.

```
 _Ｐ¶¶o¶~¶¶ *Ｆ³¶~-_
```

Print the upper right line and the interior decoration.

```
↓←×~⁶
```

Print the middle `~`s.

```
Ｆ⁴«＼↘
```

Print the lower right line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 459 bytes

```
{iii}iic{iiiiii}iiic{{d}ii}dddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iiiic{{d}ii}dc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}dddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}dd}dc{{d}ii}icc{{i}d}iiiic{{d}ii}dc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}dddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iiiic{{d}i}ddddccccc{{i}d}iiiic{{d}ii}dc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}dddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddcccc{iiiiii}c{iii}iiiicccccc{{d}}{d}ddddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddcc{i}c{d}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiicii{c}{ddd}ddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVBJDoAwCHyRjzKMxjl7JLy9gtDEHkyaKBdgmKUpthU7z2NpTUkaKdFz9Fnh3RDlC830PtTFCsUD860sbFqO0CSX8ovjiDka9dE4HNjp9UOUcoYLkPJXvYYQNvj02PdMmeCTKp6PfIG0dgE)

Uses backslashes instead.